# C# Wpf surfaceusercontrol Contact Events not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contacts, pixelsense

I have a `SurfaceWindow`. In it is a `Scatterview` with a `ScatterViewItem` and in the `Scatterviewitem` is a viewbox which contains the `SurfaceUserControl`. I added some `ContactEvents` to the control like `ContactDown`, `Contactup`, `ContactTapGesture`, etc (and the Preview versions of the events).

The only events fired are contactdown and leave. On the `Scatterviewitem` the other events work too.

Someone know why?

Sorry that i cant show you any code. I'm on work and for some reason the proxy is blocking the login to this site. I'm writing this with my phone.

Comment: Try to add some code, your question is really lacking of precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="WeltkarteSurface.SurfaceWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WeltkarteSurface"
    Title="WeltkarteSurface" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="768" Width="1024" SizeToContent="Manual" Loaded="SurfaceWindow_Loaded" >
  <s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
    </s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <s:ScatterView x:Name="MainScatterView" Background="#FFB4DCFC">
            <s:ScatterViewItem x:Name="MainScatterViewItem" MinWidth="1024" MinHeight="768" Center="512,384" CanRotate="False" Width="1024" Height="768" Background="Transparent" ScatterManipulationDelta="MainScatterViewItem_ScatterManipulationDelta" >
                <s:ScatterViewItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="MainViewbox">
                            <uc:MainMap PreviewContactTapGesture="MainMap_PreviewContactTapGesture" ContactTapGesture="MainMap_ContactTapGesture"></uc:MainMap>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </s:ScatterViewItem.Template>
            </s:ScatterViewItem>
        </s:ScatterView>
    </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

This is my Surfacewindow Code. The PreviewContactTapGesture and ContactTapGesture events on MainMap work only if they arent in the Scatterviewitem.

Thanks